# Is it bad to wrap nav bar with a new container and row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use both fluid container and container at same page because the design requires both fullwidth element and boxed elements.

1. Is it ok to use both fluid and responsive container on same page or can that mess things up?
2. Is it bad to wrap nav bar with a new container and row in a Bootstrap page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their example navbar on the documentation page is itself inside a row and container:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

They even have a `.container-fluid` still surrounding the menu inside the page...which means they are nesting containers within other containers.  So, yes, it can be inside the page.  As far as rows, containers, etc., the main issue to consider is alignment issues based on the paddings and margins.

A `.container`, like a `.col-*`, adds `20px` padding on the sides.  A `.row` adds negative margin to counteract the padding.  So, after you put the menu on the page, it if looks like it's squished in by `20px` and not aligning, then you may need to add another `.row` around it.  If it's outside of the edges, you may need to add a `.col-*` to surround and put padding on it.

As far as `.container-fluid` and `.container` on the same page.  I did this back on bootstrap2 for a client that wanted the menu and footer to be in a .container but wanted the content to stretch the entire width of the browser...and I didn't have any problems. I can't imagine bootstrap3 being any different.